# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" when it is present

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cors

I am trying to send a POST request from one website to my own website. I have made sure to explicitly allow CORS access, yet when I try to send the actual POST request I keep getting hit with the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error.

The code for the page I am trying to send the POST request to looks like:
[image]

The response headers look like:
[image]

In addition, I have tried to send the request with plain JavaScript, AJAX, and jQuery yet they all fail.

This is the jQuery attempt:
[image]

The plain JavaScript attempt:
[image]

And finally the AJAX attempt:
[image]

What am I getting wrong here?

**EDIT:** Sorry guys, I was looking at the wrong headers window. The previous screenshot was from me just looking at the address with my browser. I updated to the screenshot to show what the Network pane actually shows about the `$.post` request.

Comment: What is the HTTP status code of the response in the case where you get that error message. Use the Network pane in browser devtools to check.

Comment: HTTP status code: 301

Comment: Your question is missing a few details, according to the headers you provided you have a frame & you are using it somehow as it shows `x-frame-options sameorigin`

Comment: @ahmad — Servers which use `X-Frame-Options` **always** send it in the response. It can't be sent dynamically based on if a frame is being used to load the page or not. Nothing about the question suggests the OP is using a frame.

Comment: I'm not using any frame, all I am doing is executing the JavaScript code directly in the browser. Could that be bad?

For testing purposes I am executing the code from PasteBin just to see if it works.

Comment: Re edit: So you got a 301 redirect. There's no [mcve] so we don't know why you got a 301 redirect or why you might expect something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid solution. I forget to put `www.` after the `http://`. With the `www.` before the domain name the code works. Thanks guys for the help :).

Comment: Please just delete the question. You mistyping the URL isn't something worth preserving on Stackoverflow!

Comment: You sure? What if someone makes the same mistake? If you insist I will delete.

Comment: If someone makes the same mistake, any search term they come up with is unlikely to find this question.

Answer (score -1):

Headers is PHP must be before any output sent from the server.

Try putting the headers in the top of the file, as like this:

```
 <?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

 ...
 ?>
```

Comment: They already are. The only code above them is some PHP code which doesn't `echo` or otherwise print anything to the page. I will try moving the headers code further up, but I doubt it will change much.

Comment: Just tried this, doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

try to modify request headers

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Request-Headers: origin, x-requested-with");

...
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't work but I edited my answer because I made a mistake. Check the updated second screenshot, maybe my problem will make more sense now?

Comment: If that was the problem, the error message would complain that the headers being sent were not allowed (and it would be complaining about the preflight not the resource).